# Does Incense increase Pokemon rarity?

Tags: pokemon-go

My house seems to only be surrounded by throwaway Pokemon, Pidgey, Caterpie, Rattata, etc. Occasionally a Jigglypuff will wander by to make things exciting.

So yesterday I popped my first Incense because I didn't feel like leaving the couch so I figured they'd come to me. Suddenly I get attacked by a Vulpix (not the rarest but new to me) and I know things are going to get interesting. About 20 minutes in I see this:

[image]

A wild Electabuzz, which apparently hatches from 10km eggs so I would presume quite rare as well as a Venusaur, the final evolution of a starter so presumably rare in the wild as well, both appear nearby.

I find it hard to believe it is coincidental that during this one time period where I used an Incense all the hard hitters came out to play. Does the Incense increase the chance of rare Pokemon spawning? Is it just a law of large numbers type situation, where if it lures so many Pokemon some are bound to be rare? Or was this just extremely lucky and coincidental?

Comment: I am interested in the answer to this! I have noticed a similar thing, but I'm curious if it just seems that way due to the higher volume of pokemon that are spawned around you.

Comment: Sidenote: I caught neither because it was a thunderstorm outside...twas a sad day.

Answer (score 3):

Incense Pokemon are only seen by you, and from experience they tend to be slightly rarer than the local stuff. However, incense should not affect Pokemon visible to anyone else, so I think it's just good luck that you saw Electabuzz and Venusaur silhouettes.

Answer (score 2):

Both incense and lure modules increase the chance of rare Pokemon spawning.

I've found this out by experience.

Comment: How did you make this determination based on your experience? Specifically, how did you determine that the chance of rare Pokemon spawning increased as opposed to simply all Pokemon having an increased spawn chance?

Comment: @Ellesedil I noticed Pokemon showing up that I hadn't seen before. This happened again if I activated a new one. Both spawn rates go up, rare and common Pokemon.

Comment: So... what you're saying is that incense and lure increase the spawn rates of Pokemon. We already knew that. How do you know, specifically, that the chance of rare Pokemon spawning is increased compared to common Pokemon?

Comment: @Ellesedil I see now that I worded it weirdly, I mean that I saw an increase by both rare and common but I saw more rare/uncommon Pokemon for that location than common Pokemon. Rarer Pokemon also showed up more than the common Pokemon that I see normally.

Comment: Great, that's better. Now, how do you know it wasn't just luck? Can you prove that it is a trend?

Comment: @Ellesedil It happened everytime I tried it, now granted, it was only 4 times but either I have some great luck or there is a trend.

I just leveled up, so I guess I can try again tomorrow if you think it's still a fluke.

Answer (score 1):

I've read that there are rare Pokemon in every location, but they are (go figure) hard to find. Using incense makes all the Pokemon in your area flock to you, common or rare. So, in a sense, it does increase the amount of rare Pokemon you're likely to see, do to the pull of your enticing incense.

Answer (score 0):

I have found you get a ton of super common pokemon, like Ekans, then a few rare pokemon. I have gotten a Kabuto, a friend has gotten an Ivysaur. For example, once I got: 1 Magikarp, Countless Pidgeys and Nidorans, and a Rhydon. You can get any Pokemon from incenses, but having an Electabuzz and a Venasaur at the same time is probably coincedental good luck. There is no real increased chance of rare pokemon spawning, just some junk and maybe 1 rarer Pokemon.